# Jenkins build won't stop at all after SUCCESS

Tags: jenkins, logparser

I have a Jenkins project with a job that gets triggered whenever something new is pushed on the `jenkinstest` branch of the associated GitHub repo.

What does the job, specifically? It builds a Visual Studio Solution on `Debug` and `Release` (both x86 and x64). So, it runs `MSBuild.exe` four times. After that, it runs a Google test command using an `utilities_test.exe` executable file.

These is the command that is executed at the first step:

```
echo "Building solution file on Debug x64"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\CFT_TCA_IMS\SAB_Test\Repository\Utilities\solution_windows\utilities.sln" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="x64"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo "Build status of the solution file with <Debug x64> configuration is PASSED") Else (echo "Build status of the solution file with <Debug x64> configuration is FAILED")
```

(there are three more batch scripts for every platform). The test that follows looks like this:

```
echo off

echo "Running test on Debug x64"

"D:\Jenkins\workspace\CFT_TCA_IMS\SAB_Test\Repository\Utilities\solution_windows\x64\Debug\utilities_test.exe" --gtest_filter=CategoryName.MyTest

exit 0
```

Everything seems to work fine. The build process is triggered on push, and the test seems to pass, but there's one problem. I also use Jenkins' **Log Parser** and at the **Post-build Actions**, I've added a **Console Output (build log) parsing** action, that uses a project rule looking like that:

```
info /0 Error/
info /0 Warning/
info /(?i)errorreport/
error /(?i)error/
error /(?i)failed/
warning /(?i)warning/
info /(?i)building/
info /(?i)done/
```

Because of this, my build seems not to stop. It usually takes around 2-3 minutes for my solution to build, but I've waited like 20 minutes and nothing happened.

The solution is getting built, and the test passes, but the build process does **not** stop. The last output of my console log is:

```
13:35:10 Note: Google Test filter = CategoryName.MyTest
13:35:10 [==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
13:35:10 [----------] Global test environment set-up.
13:35:10 [----------] 1 test from CategoryName
13:35:10 [ RUN      ] CategoryName.MyTest
13:35:10 [       OK ] CategoryName.MyTest (0 ms)
13:35:10 [----------] 1 test from CategoryName (0 ms total)
13:35:10 
13:35:10 [----------] Global test environment tear-down
13:35:10 [==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
13:35:10 [  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

There's nothing about my **log parser** outputted here.
When I remove the Log Parser post-build action, everything seems to work fine. Also tried to remove everything from the parser's config file, but nothing gets fixed.

Any idea about what it could be? Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your build run on a slave ? If so, Jenkins copies log files and other artifacts back to the master after completing the build steps but before marking the build as complete. You may have a network or I/O bottleneck here.
If you can't figure out the root cause and just want to have the build terminate without intervention, you can use the build timeout plugin.